# How to remove Content-Type from Response message in wso2 ESB

Tags: header, content-type, wso2-esb

I have a api in wso2 ESB. My API like this:

```
<inSequense>
   <send>
     <Endpint key="exapleEndpint">
   </send>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
      <header action="remove" name="Content-Type" scope="transport"/>
      <send/>
<outSequence>
```

I call my api with curl like:

```
curl -i -X POST http://192.168.0.1:8280/login -F action=mobile -F user_username=3324 -F user_password=111111  -H "Accept:application/json"
```

When i call, i see Content-Type header in reponse message. How to remove this Header. I want delete Content-type and add my Content-type and parse response. The exmapleEndpint return json body but in header return Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove this property before send, in your outSequence : `<property name="Content-Type" scope="transport" action="remove"/>`

but if your goal is to change the content-type to application/json, just say wso2 to use the appropriate message Formater :  `<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>`